# KVM/QEMU: "Storage parameter error: directory is not managed on the remote host" when importing an existing image from a mounted drive

Tags: kvm-virtualization, qemu, virt-manager

A server I manage remotely has a KVM/QEMU image stored on a non-os, mounted drive `/mnt/drive`.

When I use `virt-manager` to import the disk image, I get the following error:

```
Storage parameter error.
Cannot use storage '/mnt/drive/vms/vm1.img': '/mnt/drive/vms' is not managed on the remote host.
```

I checked the directory permissions and they should be fine. What could be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a storage-pool on the host first. Something like this: https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/18/html/Virtualization_Administration_Guide/sect-partbased-storage-pool.html.